# What are reasons for NOT connecting exposed pad (EP/thermal pad) to ground?

Tags: pcb-design, grounding

For what reasons would a manufacturer suggest that the thermal pad should NOT be connected to ground?

See link and snippet from a Nordic datasheet.

https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/nordic/download_resource/9404/1/76425885

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In some cases, checking the evaluation board design would give you an answer and an insight into internal design of the IC.

Answer (score 7):

***Note: This is the response I received from Nordic Semi customer support specific to this family of ICs.***

 
When the nRF24L01+ tranceiver was made, the designers were afraid that noise would enter the radio via the center pad. So it was decided not to ground this. The nRF24LU1+ have the same radio and was the second design using this. So the decision was still to not ground the pad. When we launched the nRF24LE1, we didn't have enough ground pins, so some of the internal ground connections were downbonded to the center pad. But the radio was the still the same.

We haven't seen any issues by grounding the center pad on any of our radios, so you can say that not grounding the pad was being over-cautious. All devices since the nRF24LE1 have the center pad connected to ground.

So soldering the center pad of the nRF24LU1+ is not a problem. But how you do it depends on the layout on your boards. Any tracks / vias under the chip must be removed and replaced with a solid copper square with no solder mask. Ground this to the bottom side ground plane with a few vias. Then make a appropriate aperture in the paste mask.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the thermal pad is internally connected to another signal. I once had a design where a high power RGB LED had a thermal pad connected to the red terminal for some reason.

Needless to say, that was an interesting debug session. So don't just assume that connecting a thermal pad to GND is going to work in case the datasheet makes no mention of internal connectivity.

Comment: In the snippet above, it says it is connected to ground.

Comment: It's connected to ground for purposes of DC... which does not necessarily mean that giving it a low-impedance path to ground at *other* frequencies is a good idea.

Comment: Apparently, there is some more detail here: https://www.nordicsemi.com/kor/Nordic-FAQ/Development-tools/Layout-files/Should-we-connect-the-die-attach-pad-on-the-QFN-package

Comment: @ChrisStratton, that makes sense. This chip has a 2.4 GHz radio.

Comment: I gave +1 to this answer because it is good advice to avoid assuming that the exposed pad / thermal pad is connected to ground.

Comment: @FRob Thanks for that link. That gives a little more insight.

Comment: Also, sometimes the manufacturer have other devices that uses that pin for another function or plan to use it in the future, thus not connecting it allow for easy part exchanged in the future.